# How to convert blob file content to .docx in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-blob-storage

I have a docx template on my blob container. I wanted to populate my word document with values from a http request (see logic app diagram below). I have no idea on how to convert the result "Get blob content" to a file that I am able to populate.

Sharepoint is not a option for me.

[image]

I have read about composing on logic apps, but I am new to the tech and unable to make complex functions on it, yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can populate the word document using the blob storage. You can only populate using O365 Connectors (i.e. either SharePoint site, Teams Groups or OneDrive). You can clearly see it in the `Populate a Microsoft Word template` options connector itself.

Instead, you can try in the below-mentioned way.
[image]

I'm using Html to text in order to remove any HTML tags that are going to carry out while initializing the variables.

Here is the JSON schema that I used

```
{
"type": "object",
"properties": {
"Name": {
"type": "string"
},
"Age": {
"type": "integer"
},
"Gender": {
"type": "string"
},
"PhoneNumber": {
"type": "string"
}
}
}
```